# Prevent users without [activation having "true" value], to log in

Tags: php, validation, laravel, authentication, controller

**How to prevent users log in without mail confirmation?**

The database set correct. When user confirms the registration by clicking the link in the received message, the value "confirmed" changes from 0(default) to 1. *Of course boolean type.* I need "else if" statement to work, but I can't figure out how. Here is my code:

```
public function postSignin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if (!Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']), 
        $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with(notify()->flash("Ooops..", "error", [
            'timer' => 5000,
            'text' => 'Could not sign in with those details',
        ]));
    }
    else if ((Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password'])))&&('confirmed'===0)) 
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with(notify()->flash("Ooops..", "error", [
            'timer' => 5000,
            'text' => 'Activate your account',
        ]));
    }
    else 
    {
    return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function postSignin(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required'
   ]);

// This line will always log the user **in** if the account is confirmed or not.
if (!Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']), 
    $request->has('remember')))
{
    return redirect()->back()->with(notify()->flash("Ooops..", "error", [
        'timer' => 5000,
        'text' => 'Could not sign in with those details',
    ]));
}
else if (!Auth::attempt(["email"=>$request->input("email"),"password"=>$request->input('password'),"confirmation"=>1]) 
{
    return redirect()->back()->with(notify()->flash("Ooops..", "error", [
        'timer' => 5000,
        'text' => 'Activate your account',
    ]));
}
else 
{
return redirect()->route('home');
}
}
```

Comment: actually, it shows the activate your account message, but user logged in! I want to prevent logging in.

Comment: It is still validating as decent no matter if 'confirmed' value is true or false. I am confused

Comment: Dont be just read your code very well. The first line will always log the user in if he is confirmed or not. so you can put Auth::logut() inside the first and second if condition(sort of a hack). Will update my answer.

Comment: Oh my god, I got it!! Thank you so much!!)))